# Creating multiple processes via "fork" for one parent process

Tags: c, pipe

I would like to create a small program that will accept user input from stdin for the number of processes they would like, and then, my program will fork the n number of processes as specified by the user. Later on, I would like to pipe data from the child to the parent.

However, I want only one parent process. I have been trying to figure out the algorithm for this, and perhaps I am overcomplicating it, but I am stuck.

Do note I can only use the fork and pipe features in C (so nothing too crazy!)

Here is my algorithm.

Loop only if I am a parent process, and do not loop if I am a child process.

If I am a parent process entering the loop, then I will call fork(). Otherwise, I am a child, and I will do some child-related tasks (which I may then pipe back to the parent later on). The child should not re-enter the loop as to avoid creating children-of-children processes.

Does that make any sense?

What would you advise me to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say `n` is the number of children you get as input. Let's see what you could do, if you use one pipe for each child.

In the parent process:

```
pid_t pid;
int fd[n][2];
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    pipe(fd[i]);
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("whatever");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid == 0) {
        for(j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (close(fd[j][0]) < 0) {
                perror("closing fd[0]");
                exit(1);
            }
            if (close(fd[j][1]) < 0) {
                perror("closing fd[1]");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        func(fd[i]);
    }
}
// other parent stuff next && close file discriptors not needed
```

And your `func()` should be what the children have to do. It takes as arguments the 2 file descriptors of the child's pipe. Note that in the end of `func` you should `exit()`.

A solution making a pipe for each child would be a little better but a little more complex than that (hint: you may pass fd's as arguments, also close all fd's with caution!)

Also, you may keep each child's `pid` by defining `pid_t pid[n];` instead of `pid`, and refer to each pid as `pid[i]`.

Don't forget to wait for every child to die!

Comment: But won't this keep spawning more "parent processes"?

Comment: In fact, when I create 2 processes and I print out their pids (that is, n = 2), I get as output 

28465
0
0
28467

Comment: No if your `func` exits in the end then the child's process will exit, it will not return in your `main()`.

Comment: Is there only one pipe in your code? Because my concern is needing multiple pipes. I am reading from multiple pipes at the same time that children write to.

Comment: Well, you should define where you call that printing to check if it's what it's expected.

Comment: You should not print right after the `fork()`, because then both parent and child will print what `fork` returns (check manpage). You should print `getpid()` at the right place (inside `pid == 0` for the child and right after the if statement for the parent).
For the pipes: You can make the file descriptors as `fd[n][2]`, then in the loop you have to call `pipe(fd[i]);` and close the file descriptors a child does not need. That can be done in `else if (pid == 0)` in a `for` loop keeping only where the child can write to and sending that as argument in `func`.

Comment: It never gets to the (pid == 0) for some reason.

Comment: Typo. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer for multiple pipes. Add `printf("%d\n", getpid());` just before `func` call. The child should get in `else if (pid==0)` if everything goes right with forking

Comment: Doesn't the line "  func(fd[i]); " need to change as well?

Comment: It depends on what your function should get. With that call we pass both read and write fd's of "pipe[i]".

Comment: Gotcha. That makes sense.

Comment: For some reason my write function keeps printijng to stdout. Any ideas why that is?

Comment: At first check if there is no typo when you close fds. Then check if func is defined right (`void func(int *fd)`). I have a typo in the answer (need brackets for the 2 ifs in `for(j...)`) which I will correct. If it is nothing of these try some debugging (print the fds, all must be greater than 2)

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I would move all of the `fork()` and `pipe()` stuff into its own subroutine, with clear semantics, and call that subroutine from a loop in `main()`.

In the example below, `spawn()` forks, invokes the work function in child, ensures that the child exits appropriately, and returns in the parent.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/* Launch a child. This routine exit()s in the child and
 * return()s in the parent */
void spawn(void (*fn)(int), int *fd) {
    int pipefd[2];
    int pid;

    if(pipe(pipefd) < 0) {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(1);
    }
    switch(pid = fork()) {
    case -1:  /* Error */
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
        break;
    case 0:   /* Child */
        close(pipefd[0]); /* Kids only talk */
        fn(pipefd[1]);    /* Put the kid to work */
        exit(0);           /* Kill the kid */
        break;
    default:  /* Parent */
        close(pipefd[1]); /* Parents only listen */
        *fd = pipefd[0];
        printf("Spawning PID=%d, FD=%d\n", pid, *fd);
        break;
    }
}

int
get_number_of_children() {
    /* TODO: Do stdin-reading here and return a good number */
    return 3;
}

void do_work(int fd) {
    /* TODO: Whatever work the children might do */
    /* For example: */
    write(fd, "hello", 5);
}

int main (int ac, char **av) {
    int nkids = get_number_of_children();
    int fd_array[nkids];
    int pid;

    /* Birth the children */
    for(int i = 0; i < nkids; i++) {
        spawn(do_work, &fd_array[i]);
    }

    /* TODO: Read the data from the file descriptors in fd_array */

    /* Finally, wait for all children to die */
    while((pid = wait(0)) != -1) {
        printf("Waited PID=%d\n", pid);
    }
}
```